# Test the convergence of the series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_n$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

> Test the convergence of the series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_n$  , where
>
> $$a_n=\begin{cases}\dfrac{1}{n^2} & \text{ if $n$ is not a square integer},\\[6pt] \dfrac{1}{n^{2/3}} & \text{ if $n$ is a square integer}.\end{cases}$$

I can not understand that how I approach. I think it may be by **Integral Test**. But I am unable to apply this test.

Comment: Integral test does not apply because we require the underlying function, hence the sequence, to be monotone.

Comment: Split into two subseries. If both converge, so does their sum (it is positive terms, so convergence is absolute convergence, and thus reordering terms is allowed).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a series whose terms are all positive which means it converges if and only if it absolutely converges. Therefore we can break it up into two series and test their convergence.
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n\leq\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{n^2}+\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^{4/3}}=\frac{\pi^2}{6}+\zeta(4/3)<\infty.$$

Comment: When $n$ is square integer then $a_n=\frac{1}{n^{2/3}}$...NOT $4/3$

Comment: But we are summing over all numbers of the form $n=k^2$, so the sum is $$\sum_{\text{n is square}}\frac{1}{n^{2/3}}=\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{1}{(k^2)^{2/3}}= \sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{1}{k^{4/3}}.$$

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure which test I'd use per se, but the way I'd establish it is as follows:
$$\sum_{k=1}^n a_n \le \sum_{k=1}^n k^{-2} + \sum_{1 \le k \le \sqrt{n}} k^{-4/3} \le \sum_{k=1}^\infty k^{-2} + \sum_{k = 1}^\infty k^{-4/3} < \infty,$$
hence the partial sums are a montone increasing sequence that's bounded above, and hence convergent.